# MS Crm 2011 javascript Iframe functions

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm

I'm facing a problem with an IFrame on MS CRM 2011. I'm trying to generate HTML code and write it into an IFrame. I'm quite new to CRM development so I hope you could guide me to a solution.

After I generate the HTML content (IframeHTML) via JavaScript I try to write that content to an IFrame and then reload the whole Form. Everything is working fine until I reach my last command

```
var control = document.getElementById("IFRAME_name");
control.contentWindow.document.open();
control.contentWindow.document.write(IframeHTML);
control.contentWindow.document.close();
control.location.reload(true);
```

The script is executed on OnLoad of the Form, but it gives me an alert that

> Access is denied

at the end.

If I replace the first line with :

```
var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_name");
```

it tells me

> Document is not supported.

I'm not sure if I recognized what the problem here is so any help would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use Xrm.Page to get the IFRAME, so the first block of code you have looks good. I use very similar code in CRM 2011 (see below) and it works fine, so I'm assuming your error is due to something else.

        var iFrame = document.getElementById("IFRAME_name");
        var doc = iFrame.contentDocument;
        if (doc == undefined || doc == null) {
            doc = iFrame.contentWindow.document;
        }

        doc.open();
        doc.write(IframeHTML);
        doc.close();

Comment: Actually, a difference may be in the control.location.reload(true) line.  Do you need that line of code for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate Crossframe Scripting in the IFRAME properties.

Have you done that?

Regarding the Xrm.Page call, you can get the IFRAME using

```
var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_name").getObject();
```

This is the supported way to get the IFRAME, so you should use that.

Comment: Have you loaded a document in the IFRAME? Where do you want to put the generated code?

Comment: I'm creating onload(from the Form where the Iframe is in) some Html content and put that into the Iframe itself. It's just simple html. That worked just fine on Crm 4 but on Crm 2011 it's not. I don't know if it's because the differences of the js syntax between Crm 4 and Crm 2011...I don't load an external document in the Iframe, I just want the Iframe to show the content I'm giving to it...

Comment: I have added the supported way using Xrm.Page to get the IFRAME above, you can try that, but I think you will get the same error as you have now.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help.. Yes I'm getting the same error. I could imagine that the problem are these lines :
control.contentWindow.document.open(); 
control.contentWindow.document.write(IframeHTML); 
control.contentWindow.document.close(); 

And I cant find anything on the web about that

Comment: So now the only thing I can suggest is to check the security settings in IE.
Sorry, I do not have any further ideas at the moment.