# How to get the name of my IFRAME control?

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm-2011

In [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913468/ms-crm-2011-javascript-iframe-functions), a solution is suggested by referral to the name of an IFRAME as "*IFRAME_name*".

I'd like to know how I'm supposed to obtain that name in my CRM.

EDIT: The component I'm talking about looks like an IFRAME but is, in fact, a web resource (a HTML document **inside** CRM, i.e. not an external page). When I refer from it to CRM stuff, I go

```
parent.window.Xrm.Page + the usuals
```

but how can i refer from the CRM **down** to that component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the IFrame on the form you set a name.

Open the form customisations and read the name from there.

[image]

Comment: Weird. When I create a new IFRAME, this is what I see. But when I double-click on the already existing IFRAME, the name is not *IFRAME\_Something* but *WebResource\_Something*.

Comment: Its because you added a web resource control instead of an iframe control

Comment: Yes, my bad. Now I got it. In the DOM it's still IFRAME but CRM-wise it's a different creature. Thanks!

Comment: @GregOwens Done and done! Thanks for the patience and reminders. I'll go through my questions to see if I can check some more as answered. I think I get so excited when I get an answer so I drop everything to test the stuff, then continue working on it until I get stuck on the next thing and **then** I ask again, forgetting about the previous one. It's wrong, I understand that. I'll try to improve and kick me hard if I fail. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
console.dir(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes)
```

and then press *F12* to open the console to inspect the object. The console must be open on the page for the console variable to be recognized, so I usually refresh the page with the console open.

Use:

```
var iFrame = descriptionIFrame.contentDocument 
  || descriptionIFrame.contentWindow.document;
```

to access the IFRAME content, where *descriptionIFrame* is a reference to an IFRAME object.